# Getting undefined while destructuring (or trying to access) mongoose query object

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I'm using Next.js built-in API as my authentication API.

I have a file called login.js inside pages/api/auth which is my API for generating JWT.

I need to get user input on my login form and check those with credentials in my MongoDB using Mongoose.

I'm trying to destructure query object returned from DB for comparing it,
but what i get is undefined.

here is my code inside pages/api/auth/login.js:

```
export default async function login(req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3006')
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept')
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS')

    await mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/dashboard-db')
    const { username, password } = await req.body
    const query = await User.findOne({ usernameDB: username }, { usernameDB: 1, passwordDB: 1, _id: 0 })
    const { usernameDB, passwordDB } = query

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("Response: ", query)
        res.status(200).send({ message: "Hello World!" })
        resolve();
    })
```

But in console i get `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'usernameDB' of 'query' as it is null.`

I tried:

`query.usernameDB`

`query["usernameDB"]`

using `User.find()`

When i try to `console.log("Query: ", query)` i get

```
Query: null

Response: null

Query: { usernameDB: 'sco', passwordDB: '3168' }

Response: { usernameDB: 'sco', passwordDB: '3168' }
```

Comment: are you sure that user object has usernameDB key?

Comment: Please add the schema of `User` to your question.

Comment: @DenizKaradağ Yes i am, the strange part is i get the query object but i can't destructure it

Comment: The Mongoose docs aren't super clear on this but it seems that `findOne()` may resolve with a `null` value. You should check the value of `user`

Comment: @Phil just checked that and updated my question.

Comment: The question then is what is `getData()` and what value does it resolve with?

Comment: @Phil  getData is const getData = async () => await req.body (getting user input)

Comment: I don't have your entire code and Idk mongoose docs by heart but if you are sure that your user object exists and usernameDB key also exists, this means the moment you are trying to access the key value, it doesn't exists yet. So problem possibly comes from a timing issue. rather than using .then and chain everything, try to use async/await and put the operations in order. use await when you are supposed to wait, after that it should get resolved on its own actually.

Comment: @DenizKaradağ Thanks for your suggestion.
I did try async/await and added it to my question too.
but it seems that the query first resolves with null and then returns the actual document i don't know why.

Comment: @AliBot please [edit] your question to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Add enough code so that I or anyone else could take it and run it without needing to ask you for more information. Code does not belong here in the comments

Comment: @Phil yeah you're right i edited my question and made it as clear as i could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just about my API from next.js on port `3000` trying to respond to my react application on port `3006` which caused to force my application to send a preflight request with `OPTIONS` method (an extra request for my app to work).

It then led to problems because the first request which was a preflight request with `OPTIONS` method didn't have a body.

(my friend told me that it's not rational to have an API on a separate port from my main app when I'm working with react and next.js but I did it for testing purposes and didn't think that it may cause a bug actually ;) )